# How do I set up ZScreen to upload images to my mediawiki?

Tags: upload, mediawiki

I've set up a mediawiki with all the correct settings and enabled image uploading.
When I do this manually this all works OK.
I want to be able to upload screenshots automatically into my mediawiki using ZScreen.

There is an option to do this:
[image]

I press <kbd>Test...</kbd>, this work OK, however I'm unable to tell ZScreen to to actually get the picture into my mediawiki.

[image]

There's no option to select `mediawiki` as my destination.
How do I setup zscreen to upload to my mediawiki?

Comment: Have you tried "File Uploader" at the bottom of that menu?

Comment: @TomWijsman, Yep, but that's not the correct option

Comment: Does [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/issues/detail?id=213) help in any way?

Comment: @harrymc, no it does not, ZScreen has the mediawiki functionality, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: This issue I linked-to says that a new uploader was committed for ZScreen. Try installing the latest [ZScreen version](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/downloads/list) from Mar 19.

Answer (score 0):

The ZScreen support article [Issue 213: upload to mediawiki](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/issues/detail?id=213) seems to refer to this problem.
On Mar 18, Theone writes :

> I'll try to write the uploader to MediaWiki. 
> So, I'm assigning myself
>   to this bug.

Then the next day, he says :

> I just committed a new uploader for MediaWiki (revision 1775).
>
> I've noticed it doesn't work on all wikis though. Some wikis have
>   either disabled the API, forbidden uploads, or use a different system
>   for logging in.

I would therefore counsel to install the latest development version from Mars 19, available
from the [ZScreen Downloads](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/downloads/list).

If this doesn't work, you might add your own input in the above thread, keeping in mind
the comment about it not working for some wikis.

Comment: The problem is not that the Mediawiki functionality is not implemented, the problem is that I cannot get it to work in any version whatsoever.

Comment: You should probably get in touch with the ZScreen developers while giving the necessary details of your wiki, in case this is a bug. But uploading might also be blocked because of some parameter set in the wiki that you are trying to use. As described above, the MediaWiki uploader of ZScreen needs the upload API to be enabled, uploads to be authorized and the login to be of a certain kind. Not being a developer of ZScreen, I can't analyze whether all these conditions are fulfilled or not for your wiki.